# Native Query Result to DTO -> No converter found capable of converting from type [*.*.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to MyDTO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa (2.1.7.RELEASE) with hibernate (5.6.9.Final) as implementation -

when using native query with DTO, I am facing below error -

> no converter found capable of converting from type
> [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap]
> to type [com.abc.reports.zyx.dtos.Xcain21

My native query is as below -

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p.package_id, p.package_name FROM packages p WHERE p.account_id=:accountId AND (CASE WHEN :packageId IS NULL THEN TRUE " +
            "WHEN  p.package_id LIKE :packageId THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) limit :offset, :limit", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Xcain21> getPackageByAccountIdAndPackageId(String accountId, String packageId, int offset, int limit);
```

And my DTO is as below -

```
package com.exp.reports.traireport.dtos;

import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class Xcain21 {

        int packageId;

        String packageName;
}
```

**How can i get result of native query automatically mapped to the DTO.**

Comment: "root cause" is: Xcain21 is no `@Entity`... I suggest: https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries/

Comment: @xerx593 - the references worked like blaze +1.